# Spring for neo4j how to inject Neo4jRepository

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

All the examples I see in the official documentation is inheriting from  `Neo4jRepository<T, Long>` and not injecting.

And I also see that queries can be run with `@Query("match...")` annotation. I don't want to run `@Query` since I need to build the query in runtime.

How can I inject something like `Neo4jRepository` and use in my beans for running queries and such?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Spring Data Neo4j** you cannot run runtime-defined queries via `Repository` concept. What you can do, is to run CYPHER queries via `Session`, and here you have two options:

#### 1. Neo4j OGM

OGM is an object-graph mapping library provided by Neo4j. In short, you can create a `Session` via `Neo4jSessionFactory`, and run queries having all converting from graph data to your objects in place, the same as with `Repository`.

You can initialise factory:

```
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, "path.to.domains.package");
```

and then just open session when you need it:

```
    public Session getNeo4jSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
```

Read more on [Neo4j Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/) and [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#introduction-graph-database)

#### 2. Neo4j Drivers

It is a similar way as you can query a SQL with [JDBCTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/). You can create a session via `Driver` and get a raw data from queries. Here is an example of a service, which could help you to perform a simple transformation:

```java
@Component
public class Neo4jBoltCypherExecutor implements CypherExecutor {

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${neo4j.bolt.url}")
    private String boltUrl;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${neo4j.bolt.user}")
    private String user;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${neo4j.bolt.pass}")
    private String pass;

    private Driver neo4jDriver;


    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        AuthToken token = (pass != null && !pass.isEmpty()) ? AuthTokens.basic(user, pass) : AuthTokens.none();
        neo4jDriver = GraphDatabase
                .driver(boltUrl, token, Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE)
                .toConfig());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> run(String query, Map<String, Object> params) {
        try (Session session = neo4jDriver.session()) {
            return session.run(query, params).list(r -> r.asMap(Neo4jBoltCypherExecutor::convert));
        }
    }


    static private Object convert(Value value) {
        switch (value.type().name()) {
            case "PATH":
                return value.asList(Neo4jBoltCypherExecutor::convert);
            case "NODE":
            case "RELATIONSHIP":
                return value.asMap();
        }
        return value.asObject();
    }
}
```

Read more on [Neo4j Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/)

Comment: Really appreciated!